What would be under a 30 year old carpet pad that is a sticky reddish spots, on a concrete floor?
What would be a reddish, sticky blotches under a 30 year old carpet with padding, on a concrete floor?

An [edit] to add a picture would be helpful.

a red spotted gronkle

Might depend on whether you're in Indianapolis or Yakutsk. In any case, there's not enough information here to answer. Please see the [help] and take the [tour].

Hope it's not blood....

Most likely it's glue.
Often installers use spots of glue to hold the padding in place so it doesn't bunch up when laying the carpet.
I have seen spots and lines. Both straight and zigzag. Colors vary depending on glue.
It also could be something else. We do not know the life history of the carpet, but glue is the most likely answer.

Without pics, this is a very reasonable guess.
